# pycharm handling of <div> tag (no autoclosing)

Tags: html, pycharm, tags

Im editing html and i use a lot of div tags with bootstrap.

for example :

```
<div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="d-block img-fluid"
                            src="img/alberto.png" alt="alberto">
                            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                            <h2>Alberto Somayya</h2>
                            <h4>Executive Chef</h4>
                            <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Award winning three-star Michelin chef with wide International experience having worked closely with whos-who in the culinary world, he specializes in creating mouthwatering Indo-Italian fusion experiences. </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Each time i open a div, pycharm doesnt autocomplete with a closing /div.

And each time i close a /div pycharm doesnt autocomplete the tag and doesnt align it with the corresponding opened div.

How can i tweak it so it does what i want?

I have tried to search google and stackoverflow but didnt find anything...

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual answer is you have to buy Pycharm pro edition so it can handle  automatically